# equation of circle tangent to line with radius

Tags: circles, coordinate-systems

Find the equation of a circle tangent to line $3x + y - 2 = 0$ at $(-1,5)$ and with radius $\sqrt{10}$. I've no idea on how to do this.

Comment: What do you mean "pass through line"? Do you mean the circle intersects the given line at the given point? Or is the circle tangent to the given line at the given point?

Comment: I mean tangent I'm sorry..

Answer (score 1):

Now as per the question the circle touches the line only at one point so it is a tangent and there can be two circles touching the given line and passing through (-1,5).

so if the given line is a tangent to the circle then the centre lies on a line perpendicular to the given line, passing through (-1,5) and at a distance of $\sqrt(10)$.

[image: center passes through a line perpendicular to the given line]

slope of line perpendicular to it is $$m1*m2=-1$$ where m1=-3 which implies m2 =1/3.

let the line be y=(1/3)x+c. Now this passes through (-1,5) substitute and get c value

The resulting equation which is perpendicular to the given line is $$3y=x+16---(1)$$

so to find the circle equation we need to find the centre of the circle which can be found with the equation shown which is nothing but the distance formula$$(x-(-1))^2+(y-5)^2=(\sqrt10)^2   ---(2)$$

since the circle has a radius of $\sqrt(10)$ units which implies the centre is at a distance of $\sqrt(10)$ units from it.

solving (1) and (2) we get $$x=-4,2$$ and $$y=4,6$$

therefore the equations of two circles are $$(x-(-4))^2+(y-4)^2=(\sqrt10)^2$$ and $$(x-2)^2+(y-6)^2=(\sqrt10)^2$$

hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

Let the equation of the circle be $$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=(\sqrt{10})^2$$

As the circle passes through $(-1,5);$  we have $$(-1-h)^2+(5-k)^2=(\sqrt{10})^2$$

So, the parametric form of $(h,k)$ can be $(\sqrt{10}\cos A-1,\sqrt{10}\sin A+5)\  \ \ \  (1)$

From the Article$\#148$ of Loney's Coordinate Geometry [Book](https://archive.org/details/elementsofcoordi00loneuoft),
 the radius of a circle = the perpendicular distance of the centre from a tangent

So, we have $$\sqrt{10}=\frac{\left|3(\sqrt{10}\cos A-1)+(\sqrt{10}\sin A+5)-2\right|}{\sqrt{10}}$$

$$\iff|3\cos A+\sin A|=\sqrt{10}$$

Let $3=r\cos B,1=r\sin B\implies r=\sqrt{10}\implies|\cos(A-B)|=1\implies\cos(A-B)=\pm1$

**Case** $\#1:$ 
If $\cos(A-B)=1,A-B=2m\pi\implies \cos A=\cos B=\dfrac3{\sqrt{10}},\sin A=\sin B=\dfrac1{\sqrt{10}}$

Use $(1)$ to find $(h,k)$

**Case** $\#2:$ If $\cos(A-B)=-1,A-B=(2m+1)\pi\implies \cos A=\cdots=-\cos B,\sin A=-\sin B$

Use $(1)$ to find $(h,k)$

Answer (score -1):

Let the equation be $$10=(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2$$

$$\implies10=(a+1)^2+(b-5)^2\ \ \ \  (1)$$

Again like [equation of circle tangent to line with radius](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930926/equation-of-circle-tangent-to-line-with-radius),
$$\dfrac{3a+b-2}{\sqrt{3^2+1^2}}=\pm\sqrt{10}$$

$$3a+b-2=\pm10$$

Considering '+' sign, $$3a+b-2=10\iff b=12-3a\ \ \ \  (2)$$

Use $(1),(2)$ find $a$ and hence $b$

Similarly consider '-' sign