# How to find the equation of tangents from a given point to general circle

Tags: conic-sections

I know the formula for equation of tangents for a standard circle $x^2+y^2=a^2$ which is
$$y=mx\pm a\sqrt{1+m^2}$$
From where we can find the slope of the tangents. Is there any such equation for a circle of the form $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$

Comment: All you have to do is shift the origin to $(-g,-f)$ and replace $a$ with $\sqrt{g^2+f^2-c}$.

Comment: @ParasKhosla so the equation will be $y-f=(x-g)m\pm \sqrt{(g^2+f^2-c)(1+m^2)}$?

Comment: It will be $(y+f)=m(x+g)\pm r\sqrt{1+m^2}$.

Comment: @ParasKhosla why would it be +? Isn’t $x=X+h$ where h is the new origin?

Comment: @Aditya it wouldn't be $+$ because the standard form of a circle with centre $(-g, -f)$ is $(x-(-g))^2 +(y-(-f))^2=a^2$ where $a$ is the radius.

Answer (score 0):

For all real values (including infinite) of $m,$ the straight line will be tangent to the circle.

Hint:

For any conic in 2D $$ax^2+2hxy+by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$$,

let $y=mx+d$ be the tangent.

Replace the value of $y$ in terms of $x$ to form a quadratic equation  in $x$.

Each root will represent the abscissa of intersection.

For tangency, the two abscissas must coincide, i.e., the roots must be same

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930926/equation-of-circle-tangent-to-line-with-radius

Answer (score 0):

In the standard equation of tangent to circle $y=mx\pm a\sqrt{1+m^2}$. Replace $(x,y)$ with $(x+g,y+f)$ and radius $a$ with $r=\sqrt{g^2+f^2-c}$.
$$. $$
Hence equation of tangent to circle $x^2+y^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$  is $$y+f=m(x+g) \pm r\sqrt{1+m^2}$$

Comment: Will it $y+f$ or $y-f$? I am not sure. $x=X+h$ is the formula right?