# Find the Center of a circle given the tangent line 9x+3y+6=0 in the point A=(1,-5), the radius of the circle is 4.

Tags: geometry

A circumference is tangent to the line 9x+3y+6=0 in the point A=(1,-5), the radius of the circle is 4.
I've been trying to find the solution to this problem, but I don't know what to do anymore.

every problem that I have seen that is similar to this one has a point in the circumference, not in the tangent line.

What can I do to solve this problem? (sorry if you have difficulties understanding this, English is not my first language)

Comment: Hint: The tangent is perpendicular to the radius of the circle.

Comment: In this question the point (-1,5) **is** the point of tangency, i.e. it's on the circumference **and** the tangent line.

Comment: you have two equations and two variables to solve for. As @MathKeepsMeBusy said, one equation comes using perpendicular distance from the center (say, $h, k$) to the tangent line being the radius and the second from the equation of the circle with its center at $(h, k)$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930926/equation-of-circle-tangent-to-line-with-radius

Comment: Does this answer your question? [equation of circle tangent to line with radius](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/930926/equation-of-circle-tangent-to-line-with-radius)

Answer (score 0):

You're given the point on the circle($1,-5$), on which $9x + 3y + 6=0$ is a tangent.
Ultimately, it is given that $(1, -5)$ is the common point for Circle and tangent.

I guess you know how to find the center when you're given point on the circle, tangent and radius.